# Можно ли в Eclipse быстро извлечь текстовую строку в коде в strings.xml?

Tags: android

Для xml такая возможность есть. Когда пишем для `TextView` текст обычной строкой, среда предлагает вынести её в ресурсы, указываем новое имя и вуаля - она уже в strings.xml, а в коде только ссылка на R.id.mystring.

А java-классе также быстро можно сделать?

Comment: в Android Studio точно можно. Переходите на темную сторону, у нас есть печеньки!

Comment: @metalurgus, согласен. Но тут надо собраться с духом и силами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ставите коретку курсора на нужную строку -> Ctrl + 1 (Quick fix) -> выбираете Extract String -> ну и дальше всё как из разметки

Comment: спасибо. То что надо. Я просто не подумал, что quick fix тут работает. Обычно юзал только при ошибках в коде.

Comment: quick fix много интересных возможностей предоставляет - вынесение в отдельный метод, в константу, конвертация switch в if else и т.д.